# Block brew command but not packages in MacOs

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I’m trying to block users from using the brew command to install/delete/modify packages in our system. However, using chmod to prevent execution of the brew command also stops the users from using other homebrew packages. Anyone know how I can block JUST the brew command and nothing else?

Comment: This is confusing. You want to lock them to a certain set of packages, but still allow them to install other brew packages?